# Can a fanless mini-pc be turned on all day long?

Tags: fan, cooling

This is a technical question and I'm looking for a technical answer. I'm trying to determine whether a fanless mini-pc would handle being run as a headless system, running typical usage (like Skype, Chrome), 23 hours a day, 7days a week.

My concern is the lack of a fan.  I need the smallest piece of hardware because space is crucial, but the system requirements are nothing extreme (core 2 duo, 2Gb or 4Gb RAM, a single 60Gb-120Gb SSD drive).

Could someone tell me if a fan really is important for running an extended time, or would a system designed to run without one be assumed to be properly designed to operate that way?

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to specify, I want to run skype with multiple videocall in middle res all day, could it that overheat a fanless system?, does a fanless system's processor have its one mini fan, like in old days pc's processor? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Especially with that light usage you should be fine.  Product recommendations are out of scope for superuser.  See http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: But I would like to use it 23hours per day, 7days per week, thats a heavy usage. Which hardware should I choose? Thanks Advanced.    PD: sorry, is just that in stackoverflow they recommend me to post here.

Comment: Without a specific model, there's no way to answer the question.  Running a computer even 24/7 is something I would expect any computer to be able to handle, but the only way to get a definitive answer is to ask the manufacturer.  You could also look for reviews or complaints about the model of interest overheating.  This question isn't a request for a product recommendation, so it's OK on that count.  But without specifics, it's likely to get closed as "too broad" or "opinion based".  Can you add details?

Comment: nice circular logic:) chrome and skype typically don't max out a cpu which is the primary heat generator.  fanless pcs are designed to be used in an open space like sitting on top of a desk not in a zero airflow sealed computer desk drawer.

Comment: The "what hardware should I choose" portion of what you want to know would be off-topic here.  But if you can identify a model or two of interest through research, advice on other forums, etc., you might be able to get more specific advice as to whether, or under what conditions, it could operate around the clock.

Comment: It's impossible to know in general of course, but I would expect a properly designed fanless computer to be fine running 24/7. After an hour (or less) of use it is probably already at equilibrium, and it won't get any hotter if the situation continues unchanged for a week/month/year.

Comment: Note that you want a CPU with the lowest TDP wattage you can find. and don't assume that Core2Duo's run cooler than any other line of chips. You may even want to consider a x86-based "mobile" chip like an Atom.  Ultimately, you will have to benchmark and decide whether your cooling is sufficient with actual hardware. Companies that build appliance-like devices without fans have to try different prototype configurations to determine their product is fit, and likely, so will you.

Comment: I'm curious how it gets air flow when it's in a case. I have run a fanless system outside of a computer case. And i'm aware of a case by German company NoFen/NoFan that is made for fanless systems, so that case doesn't take a fan.

Comment: You write "does a fanless system's processor have its one mini fan, like in old days pc's processor? " <-- What old days PCs processor are you talking about.. And what on earth do you mean.   If somebody sold a fanless system with a fan then the customer could demand his money back.

Comment: You could play a game on your phone / tablet all day (until you run out of battery).The device will slow down as the heat increases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary:  Yes, its entirely practical - just get newish hardware.

Longer version and persuasive arguments:

Usage 24/7 is not necessarily heavy usage.  Heavy usage is more likely to be dependant on the amount and complexity of data being requested - for example using a word processor would be light usage, while doing video encoding or non-accellerated playback would be heavy usage.  The question ultimately comes down to how much power is being drawn and how well it can be dissipated.  I don't use Skype, but Chrome should be OK - of-course it is possible to create scenarios which tax your system.

Its entirely practical to have a passively cooled system running 24/7 - reliably.    A few things to consider -

- Newer hardware is going to be better - particularly low power intel systems.  Intel has made huge leaps in power efficiency = lower heat = easier passive cooling over the last few years.
- Systems based on an Atom or "mobile" processor will probably work better.
- Most, if not all systems will "throttle down" - ie go slower if they start getting to hot.
- Its not certain from your post why you need passive cooling.  A slow (and quiet) fan on something like an Intel NUC might be worth considering.
- Things like cellphones run 24/7 without active cooling - indeed they even do so when additional heat is pumped into the system to charge the battery.

Comment: I'd look at platform/processor family over branding, since intel kinda has a confusing mix of names. IIRC there's core based celerons, bay trail based celerons. Next generation core Ms may be passively coolable. I was about to suggest processor families, then I realised TDP is a much better metric/

Comment: Hi, thanks for everyone for your suggestions, sorry I forgot to specify the usage of that 24/7 fanless PC, please look at the question, I edited it. Thanks to all.

Comment: what if I run skype multiple videocall in middle res all day long?

Comment: You are asking a fair bit.  This is possible but video calls are processor intensive, so you will want a pretty new cpu chipset with a good GPU built into the motherboard to offload video encoding and decoding.  That said you are doing things the hard way.  There is no reason a mini PC can't be actively cooled - and indeed you can probably shrink an actively cooled system into a smaller case then a passively cooled one as you can reduce the size of the heatsink and exposed surface area.

Comment: @davidgo well there is a reason he might not want it "actively" cooled. he said FANLESS. that is his requirement, and he didn't put that up for debate. A person may want fanless for any reason, even very sensitive hearing, where it bothers them but might not bother you. And in that instance, saying "oh there's no reason why you can't have a fan" is just plain ignorant.

Comment: Thats open to interpretation.  One reasonable way of reading it is that he was wanting to to go fanless to save space.  He has also added in a bit about a fanless sysem having a fan at the end ...

Answer (score 4):

*Empirically* yes, but it depends on a hardware - a core 2 duo is seriously obsolete hardware at this point of time and probably a terrible option. *Modern* fanless PCs are typically based on atom/celeron processors or their equivilent, and often on processors that are also used on tablets.

*Historically* most of my home servers have been passively cooled machines (partially or completely), and they typically are *designed* for this, with *decently* sized, or utterly gigantic heatsinks. My observations are based on my current generation home server. My first home server was a second hand PIII with a heatsink bigger than many modern mini PCs. The second had a fan on its *chipset* and a passively cooled processor with a mini itx formfactor. The latest is a true passively cooled machines. The former have lasted over 5 years each, on a 24/7 duty cycle, and got replaced solely cause I wanted more power.

Things to look out for, as such are heat generation (TDP or SDP should be lower. I'd have an easier time cooling a 5W processor like a bay trail, than say a 45W processor), and 'thermal mass' - the size of your heatsink. Since you're relying on *natural* cooling, make sure you're somewhere air can flow and have sane ambient temperatures.

Interestingly, I have a system that has had a copy of firefox open for far too long, so I can grab some of the relevant things to look at.This is a bay trail based brix/nuc class machine. I've got 4gb of ram and a 1tb HDD. Pretty close to what a modern machine of the class you want would be. I'm running linux, but I still suspect this should be a representative set of figures. I also run it 'in the open' with lots of ventilation, though my room can get pretty hot.

With modern processors usage generates heat - they trottle down *really* well. My processor load average according to htop right now is roughly 0.2 (so ~20% of one core of the full load of my 2 cores). I'm using a fair amount of memory cause of those forgotten firefox sessions (2097gb/3848gb and almost all my swap).

My core temperatures according to lmsensors is 64 degrees C. A little toasty, but not dangerously so (Mine runs cooler than typical - there's reports of 95 degrees or more). The processor is happy up to 105 degrees C tho.

Uptime's 21 days but I reboot for updates. I've had it running 24/7 since I got it outside of that and it seems fine.

In short, get something with a *hefty* heatsink, or at least a decent sized one keep an eye on it initially and you should be fine. A *well designed* machine should handle 24/7 duty under fairly normal room temperature conditions, installed in a suitable location for its design life, especially if you arn't pushing the processor really really hard.

I wouldn't shove one of these in an airless cabinet. <strike>I also wouldn't trust say, one of those ~100 dollar chinese x86 mini pcs (while tiny) for this, at any decent level since they don't really seem to be designed to shunt away heat. I've not had any experience with these - but it shouldn't be too hard to google for someone who has tried it.</strike> I've been running those cheap mini PCs for various roles, and other than the dodgy default drives they have, they're actually fine. I still feel good *natural* ventilation is important but my views on these things have changed over the years.

Go with common sense, and running a fanless PC 24/7 under moderate loads should be fine.

Comment: what if I run skype multiple videocall in middle res all day long?

Comment: Constantly? Should still be ok. Not having done this (and I've talked about my experiences with fanless cooling for processors *extensively*), I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Natysiu16 well you could make sure you have ways to monitor the temperature. eg a program like speedfan or some better equivalent could show temperatures

Answer (score 0):

It could last longer than a system with a fan, 'cos a fan may break!

Your question seems to have the underlying idea that maybe a system with no fan just gets hotter and hotter and hotter very slowly very gradually and so 24/7 is too much for it!! But no, it doesn't work like that!! The processor is low wattage and is cooled by air flow over a heatsink.

Comment: what if I run skype multiple videocall in middle res all day long?

Comment: @Natysiu16 It has been a while since I had a fanless computer near me..and at the time I wasn't trying much video, so i'm just thinking, what might be a way of determining this.  I'm a bit wary of saying every fanless comp will be fine.. because worst case scenario, it may depend on the build..  If you want to get a good idea, then contact the manufacturer of the fanless pc, OR, if you are building it yourself, then contact the manufacturer of the individual parts e.g. (if you are using one, then a case), and the manufacturer of the video card(if it uses one).

Comment: And i'd try running it outside the case too, and i'd measure temps so I knew what was going on.   And (if I wanted to be on the safe side, i'd get a static wrist band) and touch any chips that don't have fans, so I can see if they seem very hot.  Or an infra red thermometer gun might do it.   I think a good build should do it. 'cos these things are low wattage and low wattage means low heat.   Something designed to be 5W will have had its cooler tested at max wattage...  If it's outside of a case then there's no risk of it heating up the rest of the case. A case could be fine...

Comment: I'd always monitor it anyway, the temps,  even if it wasn't under heavy load. It's good to know your fanless machine well.  And check with manufacutrer's first as worst case, it may be model specific.  If it's a really great little shop they may say they've got one at home and they'll try it out and tell you the temp. By the way, CPUs/chips are a funny thing, i've had one CPU(not fanless) but point is it ran much lower heat than another one.identical speed. (i'm not sure if it was identical model cpu, possibly was).

Comment: But i'd do that for any build, fanless or not, monitoring the temp. It's not a constant thing. But once built and if can be outside the case then testing there, if inside the case, tested there. and temp monitors.. If you wanted to be really safe you could after finding it within good parameters, set an alarm program  that monitors the temp. Or hardware that shows temp(doesn't need to fit in a bay and doesn't need to have an LCD) and it could set off an alarm if too high.